# Merge Sort using Linked List throws an odd error in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, linked-list

I have checked all of the push, pop, and peek methods and they work properly. I have attempted to debug this code in Eclipse, and after setting a breakpoint at divide(), it points straight to the line 'private Node next;' in the class Node. I am thinking it is because the parameters in divide are of the class Node. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mergeSort {

    Scanner scanner;
    Node firstNode = null;
    Node lastNode = null;
    Node currentNode = null;
    int size = 0;

    public mergeSort(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
        scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            push(scanner.nextInt());
        }
    }

    public void divide(Node tempFirstNode, Node tempLastNode, int tempSize){
        if(tempFirstNode != tempLastNode){
            Node midNode = tempFirstNode;
            for(int i = 0; i < (tempSize/2-1); i++){
                midNode = tempFirstNode.next;
            }
            divide(tempFirstNode, midNode, tempSize/2);
            divide(midNode.next, tempLastNode, tempSize-tempSize/2);
            merge(tempFirstNode, tempLastNode, midNode);
        }       
    }

    public void merge(Node firstNode, Node lastNode, Node midNode){
        Node leftHead = firstNode;
        Node rightHead = midNode.next;
        Node rightTail = lastNode;

        while(leftHead != rightHead && rightHead != rightTail.next){
            if(leftHead.data <= rightHead.data){
                if(currentNode != null){
                    currentNode.next = leftHead;
                    currentNode = leftHead;
                    leftHead = leftHead.next;
                }
                else{
                    currentNode = leftHead;
                    leftHead = leftHead.next;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(currentNode != null){
                    currentNode.next = rightHead;
                    currentNode = rightHead;
                    rightHead = rightHead.next;
                }
                else{
                    currentNode = rightHead;
                    rightHead = rightHead.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void push(int newEntry) {
        Node newNode = new Node(newEntry, firstNode);
        if(lastNode == null)
            lastNode = newNode;
        firstNode = newNode;
        size++;
    }

    public int pop(){
        int top = peek();
        if(firstNode != null)
            firstNode = firstNode.next;
        size--;
        return top;
    }

    public int peek() {
        if(firstNode != null)
            return firstNode.data;
        return (Integer) null;
    }

    class Node{

        private int data;
        private Node next;

        public Node(int newData, Node nextNode){
            data = newData;
            next = nextNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the odd error?

Comment: It's difficult to spot this kind of student code. A hard dependency on Scanner in a mergesort constructor, how would you know?

Comment: It is a NullPointerException at 'private Node next;'

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that you forgot to set the value of the last Node in your list. If it's null there will be a NullPointerException, if you try to access it. Could you maybe offer the main-method too?